# How do I calculate a salary in switch case? And then add an if statement for varying rates?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Please look at the case 2. Some workers are paid overtime. I don't know how to program this. I think the logic is correct.But it doesn't even return the salary. How do I add the arithmetic to case 2 to get a result? Can I also add an if statement to the switch case? They get paid at one rate up to forty hours and then at 1.5 hourly rate. Any help would be great thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int paycode;
    int hours;
    int salary;
    int rate;
    int overtime_rate;

    rate=10;
    overtime_rate=15;

    printf ("Please Enter employee paycode\n");
    scanf("%d",&paycode);           

    switch (paycode) {        
    case 1:
         printf ("Manager salary is $5000");
         break;
    case 2: 
       printf ("Enter hours\n");
       scanf ("%d",&hours); 

       if (hours <=40){
           salary=hours * rate;
           printf ("%d",&salary);
       }
       break;             
    default:
       printf ("No salary information");  
       break;        
   }        
    getch ();        
}
```

Comment: `printf ("%d",&salary);` -> `printf ("%d",salary);`

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @HotLicks, I hesitate to question a long-standing member who's responsible for good questions _and_ answers, but where is the request for _any_ of those things? BTW, I doubt any of your T-shirts are older than _me_ :-) Not impossible, just unlikely.

Comment: @paxdiablo - The request was implicit.

Comment: @HotLicks, phew, I think _that_ may be a harsh call. Maybe we could say there's an implicit advert in there for diet products as well, and flag it as spam :-) Me, I'd prefer to give the benefit of the doubt, _especially_ when any implicit request appears to be something read into it rather than placed there by the OP. Still, everyone has the right to vote as they see fit, and the swarm will work it out, so I won't argue the point.

Comment: @paxdiablo - The OP want's to know how to program.  That's a request for a book, tutorial, or class, as I read it.

Comment: Well, we _all_ want to know how to program, otherwise we'd be over at `basket_weaving.com` or `thirteenth_century_torture_devices.com`:-) And, if OP had _asked_ "how do I program?", I would have come down on them like a ton of bricks (or just close as too broad). But this was a very _specific_ question IMO. Still, you made me break my promise not to comment further so now I'm annoyed at myself, just had to get my viewpoint out there, it's a particular character deficiency of mine.

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be a simple matter of something like:

```
case 2:
    // Get the hours.

    printf ("Enter hours\n");
    scanf ("%d",&hours); 

    // Select pay based on rates and hours worked.

    if (hours <= 40)
        salary = hours * rate;
    else
        salary = 40 * rate + (hours - 40) * overtime_rate;

    // Print pay, note lack of & address-of operator.

    printf ("%d", salary);
}
break;
```

Your main problems were:

- not setting `salary` in cases where overtime was worked.
- Using the address of `salary` when printing (this is okay for `scanf` but not for `printf`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without a explicit if, and simple print the result after the calculation.

```
   salary = (hours <= 40) ?  hours * rate : (40 * rate) + ((hours - 40) * overtime_rate);
   printf ("%d",salary);
```

A note: the "salary" don't need to be dereferenced (&).

Answer (score 0):

This is printing the address where the value of `salary` is stored

```
printf ("%d",&salary);
```

change it to

```
printf ("%d", salary);
/*           ^ remove the & */
```

and of course you can add an `if` statement inside the case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an `else` statement after `if (hours < 40)`.

Code:

```
if (hours <=40)
{
    salary = hours * rate;
}
else
{
    salary = 40 * rate;   //40 hours, normal rate
    salary += (hours-40) * overtime_rate; //(hours-40) hours, overtime rate
}
printf ("%d",salary); //You were printing the address of variable salary
```